# When is ArrayFormula interchangable for curly braces?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have some pattern and then want to check, which rows contain that pattern. In the end I want to print out the predicates, like in the image.

Why do I need to use ArrayFormula instead of curly braces?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curly ones can be used on an array only if you reference a range. example:

```
={A1:A10}
```

---

```
={A1:A10, D1:D10}
```

in any other case you will need ArrayFormula type fx. the most common is ArrayFormula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A10&"×")
```

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(A1:A10&"x")
```

and ofc partially even `FILTER` doesn't require AF wrapping